# Why custom ErrorWidget.builder is not called?

Tags: flutter

I have the following `ErrorWidget.builder` defined on `main.dart`

```
void main() {
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget> [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35),
            child: Directionality(
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.briefcaseMedical, size: 60, color: Colors.grey,)),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30),
            child: Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              child: Text(
                'Oops, something went wrong',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18), textAlign: TextAlign.center
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 30, right: 30),
            child: Directionality(
              textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              child: Text(
                'There was an unexpected problem processing your operation',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 14), textAlign: TextAlign.center
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  };
```

And the following stateful widget build implementation

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Incident"),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getDepartmentsFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            try {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                throw snapshot.error;
              }
              ...
            } on HttpException catch (e, s) {
              if (e.statusCode == 401 || e.statusCode == 403) {
                return onAuthenticationError(context: context, exception: e, stack: s);
              } else {
                return onFatalError(context: context, exception: e, stack: s);
              }
            } catch (e,s) {
              return onFatalError(context: context, exception: e, stack: s);
            }
          }));
}
```

method `onFatalError` is the one returning the ErrorWidget and it's implemented like this

```
Widget onFatalError(
    {@required BuildContext context, dynamic exception, StackTrace stack, String errorMessage}) {
  ....
  return ErrorWidget(exception);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `ErrorWidget.builder` is not called if `ErrorWidget` is returned by `onFatalError`. If I don't catch the exception and keep it unhandled, then the `ErrorWidget.builder` is called. Is this how `ErrorWidget` is supposed to work? Does it only work as expected on unhandled exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

ErrorWidget is red screen errors Widget

> As per the docs, Flutter generates red screen error whenever a widget
>   fails to build. If you take a peek into StatefulWidget.dart class, you
>   will see this code being invoken in performRebuild() method:

```
@override
void performRebuild() {
  //..//
  try {
    built = build();
    debugWidgetBuilderValue(widget, built);
  } catch (e, stack) {
    built = ErrorWidget.builder(_debugReportException('building $this', e, stack));
  }
 //..//
}
```

> In this you can see this Red Screen Error is nothing but a widget
>   named ErrorWidget provided by framework.

look this article : https://medium.com/flutterpub/showing-custom-flutter-red-screen-error-c67412f3cec

if you want handle your exceptions like http errors you should write your custom class widget and call it when you face an exception